# Execute animation when button clicked flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, dart-null-safety

I am creating a flutter web where is created home and about widget in column and uses SlideTransition on about widget but the thing is when the page load the animation happen even I am on Home widget.

I want when i click on about widget then the animation will occur not at the start of page.
how to do that?

Here is my code:

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool aboutClick = false;
  bool servicesClick = false;
  bool contactClick = false;
  final fname = TextEditingController();
  final lname = TextEditingController();
  final email = TextEditingController();
  final phoneNo = TextEditingController();
  final message = TextEditingController();
  final emailVerificationSyntax = RegExp(
      r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+");
  final homeKey = GlobalKey();
  final aboutKey = GlobalKey();
  final servicesKey = GlobalKey();
  final contactKey = GlobalKey();
  AnimationController? animationController;
  Animation<Offset>? _animationValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    )..forward();
    _animationValue = Tween<Offset>(
            begin: const Offset(-0.5, 0.0), end: const Offset(0.0, 0.0))
        .animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController!,
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
      ),
    );

    // animationController!.addStatusListener((status) {
    //   if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
    //     animationController!.reverse();
    //   } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
    //     animationController!.forward();
    //   }
    // });
    // animationController!.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= 910
        ? const MobileMainPage()
        : Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            appBar: AppBar(
              toolbarHeight: 100,
              flexibleSpace: Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 100,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    RichText(
                      textScaleFactor: 1.3,
                      text: const TextSpan(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 25,
                        ),
                        children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                            text: "Rizwan",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 40,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontFamily: "Joining",
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextSpan(
                            text: " •",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 50,
                              color: Colors.green,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontFamily: "Joining",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Scrollable.ensureVisible(homeKey.currentContext!,
                                duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                curve: Curves.ease);
                          },
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom().copyWith(
                              animationDuration:
                                  const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                              textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                                (states) {
                                  if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
                                    return const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 35,
                                    );
                                  }
                                  return const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 30,
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                              foregroundColor:
                                  MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                                if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
                                  return Colors.green;
                                }
                                return Colors.white;
                              })),
                          child: const Text(
                            "Home",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "Simple",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Scrollable.ensureVisible(aboutKey.currentContext!,
                                duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                curve: Curves.ease);
                            setState(() {
                              aboutClick = true;
                            });
                          },
                          style: TextButton.styleFrom().copyWith(
                              animationDuration:
                                  const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                              textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                                (states) {
                                  if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
                                    return const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 35,
                                    );
                                  }
                                  return const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 30,
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                              foregroundColor:
                                  MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
                                if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
                                  return Colors.green;
                                }
                                return Colors.white;
                              })),
                          child: const Text(
                            "About",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "Simple",
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  homeWidget(homeKey),
                  aboutWidget(aboutKey, _animationValue),
                  servicesWidget(servicesKey),
                  contactWidget(contactKey, fname, lname, email, phoneNo,
                      message, emailVerificationSyntax)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
  }

  homeWidget(GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>> homeKey) {
    return Row(
      key: homeKey,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 160,
            ),
            const Text(
              "Hi, I am",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 60,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            const Text(
              "RIZWAN ALI",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 70,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontFamily: "Shade",
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            DefaultTextStyle(
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.grey),
              child: AnimatedTextKit(
                pause: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                repeatForever: true,
                animatedTexts: [
                  TypewriterAnimatedText(
                    'Flutter Developer',
                    speed: const Duration(
                      milliseconds: 90,
                    ),
                    curve: Curves.linear,
                  ),
                  TypewriterAnimatedText(
                    'Android Native Developer',
                    speed: const Duration(
                      milliseconds: 90,
                    ),
                    curve: Curves.linear,
                  ),
                  TypewriterAnimatedText(
                    'Web Developer',
                    speed: const Duration(
                      milliseconds: 90,
                    ),
                    curve: Curves.linear,
                  ),
                  TypewriterAnimatedText(
                    'Freelancer',
                    speed: const Duration(
                      milliseconds: 90,
                    ),
                    curve: Curves.linear,
                  ),
                  TypewriterAnimatedText(
                    'Photographer',
                    speed: const Duration(
                      milliseconds: 90,
                    ),
                    curve: Curves.linear,
                  ),
                  TypewriterAnimatedText(
                    'Cricketer',
                    speed: const Duration(
                      milliseconds: 90,
                    ),
                    curve: Curves.linear,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              ),
              child: const Text(
                "Download CV",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 40,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70.0),
          child: Container(
            width: 450,
            height: 450,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("me.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  aboutWidget(GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>> aboutKey,
      Animation<Offset>? animationValue) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: animationValue!,
      child: Padding(
        key: aboutKey,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 600,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "ABOUT",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 35,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontFamily: "Simple",
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 700,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Wrap(
                    children: const [
                      Text(
                        "I'm a Flutter and Android Native Developer building Applications that leads to the success of the overall product. Check out some of my work in the Work section. I also like sharing content related to the stuff that I have learned in Flutter Development so it can help other people of the Dev Community. Feel free to Connect or Follow me on my Linkedin where I post useful content related to Web Development and Programming. I'm open to Job opportunities where I can contribute, learn and grow. If you have a good opportunity that matches my skills and experience then don't hesitate to contact me.",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 120,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(221, 49, 40, 40),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(15),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 15,
                          height: 15,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(15),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 200,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(221, 49, 40, 40),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(15),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 15,
                          height: 15,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(15),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 200,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(221, 49, 40, 40),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(15),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 15,
                          height: 15,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(15),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 200,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(221, 49, 40, 40),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(15),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 15,
                          height: 15,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(15),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: const [
                    Text(
                      "Name",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 200,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Email",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 180,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Linkedin",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 180,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Phone",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      "RIZWAN ALI",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 90,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      "rizwanali96960@gmail.com",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 50,
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        final url = Uri.parse(
                            "https://www.linkedin.com/in/rizwan-ali-361514212");
                        if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
                          await launchUrl(
                            url,
                          );
                        }
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        "Linkedin-Profile",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 90,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      "+92 307 4500296",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 45,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    "LET'S TALK",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 35,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not start the animation during `initState`, if you don't want the animation to play right away.

In your code:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    )..forward(); // <----- REMOVE THIS PART
```

In your code above, you should remove the `..forward()` during the initialization. This will prevent it to run at the start of the page.

Next, in the button click event, you can call `animationController.forward()` and it should begin the animation. You can also specify a starting point, e.g. `animationController.forward(from: 0)`, to ensure the animation always starts at the very beginning.

Comment: It's working the right way but how to ensure the animation execute only one time on button click. Like for example I clicked on about button the animation will execute but if I click again after some time the animation must not execute for about button?

Comment: @RIZWANALI If you only want the animation to run for the first time, you can have a boolean variable to remember whether the button has been clicked before.

Comment: Thank you I solved this before your response by doing same.
Now I created animationController for all my AppBar buttons but the issue is if I click on about->services->contact button respectively the animation works fine but if change the order like about->contact then the widget between them appears at the corner from where the slide transition begins.

Comment: @RIZWANALI if you have further questions, please close this one and open a new question.